# Get the partition number of a record before producing in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic

I need to know the partition number of Kafka topic to which a Kafka record goes.

Before the execution of

```
producer.send(record);
```

Is there any way to know to which partition that record goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible using the default round-robin partitioner. If you specify a key you could get the default algorithm from the Producer source code and try to predict (it's kind of `hash(key) % num.partitions`)
If you use a custom partitioner you process it and already know.
I was wondering about the ProducerInterceptor but it provides information before the partition is assigned as you can see from doc.

https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html

Answer (score 1):

I see three options here:

- either you specify the partition in your ProducerRecord as shown in the constructor of the [ProducerRecord class](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)
- define a custom partitioner as shown in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946420/how-to-distribute-data-evenly-in-kafka-producing-messages-through-spark)
- make use of the `AdminClient` API called [DescribeTopicsResult](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/DescribeTopicsResult.html) to get the information on the number of partitions of a particular topic and then re-apply the default partitioner logic used by Kafka:

```
kafka.common.utils.Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
```